# script inside windowbuilder (Eclipse, Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

So i just started with eclipse and java script and i am also  a new coder. I started of wtih this random name picker project. And the code is written like this:

```
public static void gods() {
        System.out.println("You have to play this God:");
        String[] gods =
                {"Agni",
                "Ah Muzen Cab",
                "Ah Puch",
                "Amaterasu",
                "Anhur",
                "Anubis",
                "Ao Kuang",
                "Aphrodite",
                "Apollo",
                "Arachne",
                "Ares",
                "Artemis",
                "Athena",
                "Awilix",
                "Bacchus",
                "Bakasura",
                "Bastet",
                "Bellona",
                "Cabrakan",
                "Chaac",
                "Change",
                "Chiron",
                "Chronos",
                "Cupid",
                "Fenrir",
                "Geb",
                "Guan Yu",
                "Hades",
                "He Bo",
                "Hel",
                "Hercules",
                "Hou Yi",
                "Hun Batz",
                "Isis",
                "Janus",
                "Kali",
                "Khepri",
                "Kukulkan",
                "Kumbhakarna",
                "Loki",
                "Medusa",
                "Mercury",
                "Ne Zha",
                "Neith",
                "Nemesis",
                "Nox",
                "Nu Wa",
                "Odin",
                "Osiris",
                "Poseidon",
                "Ra",
                "Rama",
                "Ratatoskr",
                "Ravana",
                "Scylla",
                "Serqet",
                "Sobek",
                "Sol",
                "Sun Wukong",
                "Sylvanus",
                "Thanatos",
                "Thor",
                "Tyr",
                "Ullr",
                "Vamana",
                "Vulcan",
                "Xbalanque",
                "Xing Tian",
                "Ymir",
                "Zeus",
                "Zhong Kui"};
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList(gods);
        int index = new Random().nextInt(names.size());
        String name = names.get(index);
        System.out.print(name + " ");
    }


    public static void roles() {
        String[] roles = {" Solo", " Jungle", " Mid", " ADC", " Support"};
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList(roles);
        int index = new Random().nextInt(names.size());
        String name = names.get(index);
        System.out.print(name + " ");}

public void Randomize() {
    System.out.println("Here you have your god:");
        gods();
    System.out.println("Here you have your role:"); 
        roles();}
```

But i want to import or set in this code inside my windowbuilder plugin. I have tried inserting it inside a JButton as an "actionPerformed" but when i launched the program and clicked the button it opened up the console in eclipse when i want it to open inside the program.

This is my windowbuilder code:

```
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Plswork window = new Plswork();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Plswork() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    txtAronErDu = new JTextField();
    txtAronErDu.setFont(new Font("SWTOR Trajan", Font.PLAIN, 22));
    txtAronErDu.setText("Aron er du homofil?");
    txtAronErDu.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 39);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtAronErDu);
    txtAronErDu.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(199, 118, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
}



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

PS: This is how it looks when i imoprt it:

public class Plswork {

```
private JFrame frame;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Plswork window = new Plswork();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Sebbe");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("You have to play this God:");
            String[] gods =
                    {"Agni",
                    "Ah Muzen Cab",
                    "Ah Puch",
                    "Amaterasu",
                    "Anhur",
                    "Anubis",
                    "Ao Kuang",
                    "Aphrodite",
                    "Apollo",
                    "Arachne",
                    "Ares",
                    "Artemis",
                    "Athena",
                    "Awilix",
                    "Bacchus",
                    "Bakasura",
                    "Bastet",
                    "Bellona",
                    "Cabrakan",
                    "Chaac",
                    "Change",
                    "Chiron",
                    "Chronos",
                    "Cupid",
                    "Fenrir",
                    "Geb",
                    "Guan Yu",
                    "Hades",
                    "He Bo",
                    "Hel",
                    "Hercules",
                    "Hou Yi",
                    "Hun Batz",
                    "Isis",
                    "Janus",
                    "Kali",
                    "Khepri",
                    "Kukulkan",
                    "Kumbhakarna",
                    "Loki",
                    "Medusa",
                    "Mercury",
                    "Ne Zha",
                    "Neith",
                    "Nemesis",
                    "Nox",
                    "Nu Wa",
                    "Odin",
                    "Osiris",
                    "Poseidon",
                    "Ra",
                    "Rama",
                    "Ratatoskr",
                    "Ravana",
                    "Scylla",
                    "Serqet",
                    "Sobek",
                    "Sol",
                    "Sun Wukong",
                    "Sylvanus",
                    "Thanatos",
                    "Thor",
                    "Tyr",
                    "Ullr",
                    "Vamana",
                    "Vulcan",
                    "Xbalanque",
                    "Xing Tian",
                    "Ymir",
                    "Zeus",
                    "Zhong Kui"};
            List<String> names = Arrays.asList(gods);
            int index = new Random().nextInt(names.size());
            String name = names.get(index);
            System.out.print(name + " ");
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(167, 117, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
}



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally, you should include the minimal relevant source code directly in the question, rather than linking to an external source. External links can eventually go dead, and when that happens, your question no longer makes sense.

Comment: Java and Javascript are two completely different languages, don't confuse them. What you have here is just Java.

Comment: Off-topic: Smite FTW!